# Monaco Editor - how to disable errors (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco for Typescript code with the [ngx-monaco-editor](https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor) library. Everything works great except that I want to disable the errors.

[image]

How can I disable

- all errors (like syntax, imports not found, anything)
- selective like 'experimental decorators'

I can see that the library is calling

```
this.initMonaco(options, this.code, this.language);
```

..but options seem to the only editor options, not typescript compiler options, and code and language, just strings.

How can I tell monaco what compiler options to use?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/111. Also found the compiler options: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.compileroptions.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try calling this method:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
  noSemanticValidation: true,
  noSyntaxValidation: true,
});
```

It will prevent any kind of semantic or syntax errors in your monaco code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also specifically disable individual errors

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
  diagnosticCodesToIgnore: [1109]
})
```

`1109` is an example of the error code shown in the hover tooltip in Monaco. Add whichever errors you want to hide to that array.